# rails 3.1 assets are not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, assets

I started playing around with rails 3.1.rc4 but the first problem I'm having is that the assets are not available. I created a brand new project and in the index page the rails image gives 404. Actually any assets are available.

I checked

```rb
# application.rb
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

And I tried

```rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images"
```

and also from the shell

```sh
$ rake rails:update
$ rake assets:clean
$ rake assets:precompile
```

had no luck, so I destroyed the gemset and I made another one reinstalling rails, but nothing worked so far.

Any ideas? - thank you

Comment: And yes... the file is there `app/assets/images` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it by forcing Rails to use sprockets beta10 instead of beta12 in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.10'
```

And then running

```
bundle update sprockets
```

Another fix might be to install Rails 3.1.0rc5. The problem seems to be incompatibility between Rails and Sprockets and is detailed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1810). I guess this problem will be resolved when the final version of Rails 3.1 arrives.