# Server Error 500 when fetching rdoc gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

I am trying to run a bundle update on my Mac which has been upgraded to Lion.

It is consistently failing to fetch rdoc, with the following error.

```
/Users/anita/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/remote_fetcher.rb:215:in `fetch_http': bad response Internal Server Error 500 
(http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/rdoc-3.9.1.gem) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
```

Is this likely to be something I can fix, or is it a problem with rubygems or rdoc that I can expect to see clear itself?

Other gems are downloading and installing correctly. I don't directly call for rdoc in my Gemfile, but I have tried adding it with a specific (lower) version, and I get the same error. I also get the same error from a `gem install rdoc`.

Here are the contents of my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'     , '>=3.1.0.rc5'
gem 'sprockets', '>= 2.0.0.beta.10' 
gem 'mysql2'

gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.4'

# Asset template engines
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'remotipart', "~> 0.4"
gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'      
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

All is OK if I use Rails 3.1.0.rc1, or rc2, or rc3. But they seem to have a problem (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883519/rails-3-1-assets-are-not-available) ) with sprockets. The recommendation is to go to rails 3.1.0rc5. It is when I try to do that (and at rc4) that I see the problem fetching rdoc. An alternative to rails 3.1.0rc5 is to use an earlier release of sprocket but I have had no luck with that either.

```
Could not find gem 'sprockets (= 2.0.0.beta.10)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Comment: Despite assurances that the problem couldn't possible be the firewall this was eventually resolved by changing the firewall rules to exclude rubygems from virus scanning and file caching.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by upgrading to Rails 3.1.0rc6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow I didn't see it earlier.